# vertically center the unordered list with class list-inline inside a div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to vertically center the unordered list '.header-top-widget' inside a div. But no way it is being centered.

I have tried:

```
.header-top-widget
{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```css
.header-top-widget a,
.header-top-social a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.header-top {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0e2737;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="header">
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="header-top-widget">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="instagram" target="_blank" class="nav-link">
                                    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> 96 Ernser Vista Suite 437, NY, US
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="instagram" target="_blank" class="nav-link">
                                    <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> (123) 456-78-910
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-top-social">
                        <ul class="header-top-social list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="instagram" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="twitter" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="facebook" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="linkedin" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="skype" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="">

        </nav>
    </header>
```

Why is ul not being centered in the div with flexbox? Am I doing anything wrong semantically? I have referred to various questions in SO. This may be duplicate but I am not able to solve this while trying various options.

Please help with the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround could be having different line heights for the socials and widgets.

```css
.header-top-widget a,
.header-top-social a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

/* smaller widget line height */
.header-top-widget a{
  line-height: 30px;
}

.header-top {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0e2737;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="header">
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="header-top-widget">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="instagram" target="_blank" class="nav-link">
                                    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> 96 Ernser Vista Suite 437, NY, US
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="instagram" target="_blank" class="nav-link">
                                    <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> (123) 456-78-910
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-top-social">
                        <ul class="header-top-social list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="instagram" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="twitter" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="facebook" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="linkedin" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="url" title="skype" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="">

        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: so is 30px an exact height to make the ul in the center?

Comment: I ballparked the height, you can play around with it to find exact height you need.